# Which release should I install, given my system specs?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, unity, installation, 12.04

I'm new to Ubuntu and am trying to run something better than 10.04. I have a Toshiba with the following:
1gb ram
1.86ghz processor
ATI mobility radeon 600x.

I was wondering which version I should use and if I could update something in the system to make a newer version work. I have booted 11.10 successfully twice but it usually gets the background image after the log in and stops, both from installs from wubi and a live cd.

Is there a good update for a graphics driver I should use and what would boot better, a live cd or wubi?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the latest Ubuntu on this system.  1GB RAM is fine, and the CPU and graphics should at least work.

Have you tried installing, say, 12.04 and run into any problems?  If so, tell us what they were (possibly start a new question).

I can't explain the issue with your 11.10 install, but if it is getting to the login screen that's a good sign.  It's possible that there is a problem starting compiz, which is the window manager normally started right after login and requires certain 3D hardware (which doesn't necessarily mean your card is not good enough, but that there could be a driver problem or you need a proprietary driver).  At the login screen, after clicking on your username, you could try selecting a different type of desktop session.  I can't remember if 11.10 had Ubuntu 2D or Gnome fallback as session options installed by default.

But again, don't be afraid to try 12.04 as well.  In theory at least, each new release should support more hardware and fix some bugs.

Comment: I'd def try 12.04.  I have an (seemingly older) Toshiba with a 1.8g proc, 1.5g ram (upgraded from 512M) and horrible intel graphics, and its runs smooth as silk installed.